# How to get an Hourglass pattern in c++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to get this hourglass pattern, for a while now and I have been stuck on how to proceed, it require the user to input the number of #'s in the top row and to indicate the number of rows. If the number of #'s is less than 3 it prints an error message. If the number of rows is less than 1 it is invalid or if it has less than 2 '#' 's .

**Anyway I keep getting this pattern if I input 7 for the top row and 3 for the number of rows.**

**7 #'s at the top**

**5 #'s in the next row**

**3 #'s in the next row**

**3 #'s in the next row**

**5 #'s in the next row**

**7 #'s in the next row**

And I don't need one of the rows with 3 #'s but I can't seem to get rid of it.

Anyway here is my code :

```
   // Declare and initialize variables

    int topRow(0);
    int row(0);
    int i(0);
    int k(0);
    int j(0);


  // Repeatedly prompt for top row size until valid value is entered

cout << "Enter size of the top row: " ;
cin >> topRow;

    while(topRow < 3)
    {
    cout << "Size of the top tow must be at least three." << endl;
    cout << "Enter size of the top row again: "; 
    cin >> topRow;
    }


  // Repeatedly prompt for the number of rows until valid value is entered

cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
cin >> row;

    while(row == 0 || topRow/row < 2.0  || row < 1.0 )
    {
    cout << "Invalid number of rows." << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of top row again: "; 
    cin >> row;
    }


  // Print the hour glass
cout << endl;

    for (i=1; i < topRow ; i++)
    {
        if (i <= row )
        {   for (j=1; j <= i-1; j++)
            { 
            cout << " ";
            }
            for (k=1; k <= topRow - (i*2 - 2) ; k++)
            {
            cout << "#";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else 
        {   
            for (j = row ; j >= i - (row - 1); j--)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            for (k = row ; k >= topRow - (i*2 - 2); k--)
            {
               cout <<"#";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
}

  // end program
  return 0;
```

Comment: Please add examples of valid input, what the output should be then, and what the output actually is.

Comment: You don't need to post input routines.  That's over half of your post taken up with stuff that doesn't matter.  Just hardcode the input values into your program.

Comment: The program requires that I let numbers be input by the user, so I can't just hardcode it, I also bolded what the output should look like in the top.

Comment: @Carmine The point I'm making is that it doesn't matter how or where the input comes from.  If you can't print the stars, what good is it if your input routines are "great"?  Assume the input is good, now can you print the stars?

Comment: I can print the structure however I get an extra row that isn't necessary that I am trying to get rid of

Comment: @Carmine -- You could simplify your entire approach to the problem realizing that `std::string` has a constructor that takes a repeat count and a character.  There is no need for the `j` and `k` loops, as you can simply construct the entire "space string" and "# string" in two lines.  After that, output those two strings on one line.  `std::string s1(numSpaces, ' '); std::string s2(numSymbols, '#')` then just `cout << s1 << s2 << "\n";` in the `i` loop.  The issue is now computing `numSpaces` and `numSymbols` while in the `i` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check to the first iteration of the second half of the hourglass.   If

Although messy, that would like this:

```
static bool first = true;
if (first) {
  first = false;
} else {
  // ... second print code
}
```

The input of 7 and 3 will now be:

```
#######
 #####
  ###
 #####
#######
```

---

If you are expecting other inputs to be correctly formatted, you have a much larger problem.
I suggest you rework your algorithm.